# Detect visibility of the fragment inside a navigation drawer

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

I have a fragment in the SDK that the wrapper application may display in the navigation drawer. I want to detect when this fragment will be visible to the user, for tracking purposes, from the Fragment itself. Is there any way to do it ?

Comment: use setUserVisibleHint method to know when your fragment is visible to user

Comment: Is this a callback? I used it in the fragment but received no callbacks ?

Comment: yes it is overrided method

Comment: It only works when fragment is inside FragmentPagerAdapter while using ViewPager.

Comment: no thst's not true

Comment: why don't you create a sample and try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {

    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_fragment, container, false);

        // walk up the view tree and look for the DrawerLayout
        for (ViewParent parent = container.getParent(); parent != null; parent = parent.getParent()) {

            if (parent instanceof DrawerLayout) {

                mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) parent;
                mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(new DrawerLayout.SimpleDrawerListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                        onShown();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
                        onHidden();
                    }

                });
                break;
            }
        }

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        if (mDrawerLayout != null) {
            mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(null);
        }
        super.onDestroyView();
    }

    private void onShown() {
        // ...
    }

    private void onHidden() {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of using container (which was returning null) I used getView inside  onActivityCreated to get the proper view hierarchy. Thanks for your answer. It helped!